# Logitech K520 keyboard seems to pause

Tags: windows-10, logitech-keyboard

I have a logitech k520 keyboard that seems to pause some times while playing games.  I have checked and the drivers are up to date, and I don't believe it is because of wireless interference, because my mouse continues to work fine during the apparent outages.

Both the keyboard and mouse are logitech and are using the same unifying receiver, and since the mouse is fine that doesn't seem to be likely cause.

I have put new batteries in the keyboard even though, when checked through the software, the batteries appeared fine.

OS is windows 10 pro x64 (build 15063.674).  Not sure that it matters, but the machine has an i5-4690, 16GB of ram, and an asus mother board.

The issue seems to only come up while gaming, in both resource intensive games and pretty low resource consumers.

Edit: found a partial answer while researching this issue some more. I found a recommendation to move the Logitech USB fob away from any active USB 3 ports. I did this, and while the problem still comes up occasionally it is much less frequent them before. This is kind of a shitty option though as it means either the front or back ports on my machine are a no go for USB 3 connections. I am looking for a replacement keyboard and mouse.

Comment: I've used several of those k520 combos over the years. I can tell you that the delays on the keyboard are very much an issue with these. The mouse will work fine, but the keyboard will puke out. It's so annoying that I switched back to using corded keyboards in some cases. I believe it is some kind of wireless interference, but I'm not sure. I just stopped using them. I tried exchanging them, and trying them on different computers in completely different parts of the building, and it made no difference to the problem at all. In other cases, they have worked fine.

Comment: Try to use your K520 keyboard on another computer, if still pause, it’s K520’s problem, contact Logitech.
If it runs fine, system issue, create a new account and run your game again.

Comment: I don't have another machine handy to set games up on.  Given that the keyboard and mouse are both using the same wireless receiver, and the mouse works through the outages, is it still likely that the keyboard is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of googling and poking around different forums, I found a recommendation to make sure that the logitech receiver is as far away from any used USB 3.0 devices as possible.  That seems to have taken care of the problem.  I no longer see any pauses or input lag.

Answer (score 1):

Think it's probably a keyboard issue. My keyboard was working fine for about 2 years, then some of the keys started getting stuck, and since yesterday, I get intermittent pauses when typing. Sometimes, the letters appear after 30-40s, other times, they don't appear at all. Used it on another machine and the same thing happens. One of them was running Linux and the other Ubuntu.

The mouse died about 2 months ago and I paired it with another mouse. Doesn't seem like an issue with the new mouse.